# Center-centered menu loosing elements in Webkit-browsers only

Tags: html, css, menu

I have the following problem.

I have a menu which is 1000px wide. The menu is center-centered using padding between the LIs. It's working great in all browser (even IE7), except webkit (Chrome and Safari).

For some reason, it cuts of the elements both in both directions (looks to me like it thinks the menu is not 1000px wide). I have no idea why this is happening, and I've tried to change my CSS, but I just can't get it to work.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T8PfP/ (tested in Opera, IE9, IE8 and Firefox without any problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing in this way

```
#meny ul li {
   ...
   display: inline-block;
}
```

the menu looks the same in webkit - Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/3gJEE/

Comment: I've spent so much time looking at this CSS, can't believe I did not try that. I love you. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Damnit. Well. Thanks anyway. Saved my day at the office :)